# How do I pull my data from my json file in the public folder in nextjs 13.3

Tags: reactjs, json, next.js, fetch, next.js13

I'm trying to pull my json data in the public folder.

```
async function getData() {
  try {
    const res = await fetch('/data.json');
    const data = await res.json();

    return data;
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e.message);
  }
}
```

And then I call that function in my component.

```
export default async function NotesPage() {
  const data = await getData();

  return ...
}
```

I get Error:

> Failed to parse URL from /data.json

Comment: Is the JSON already there at build time? Check the note at the bottom of the page here: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving If it's not, you ought to set up an API route and go from there

Comment: yes it's there at build time

Answer (score 0):

fetch is expecting an url and `/data.json` is not one, so if fails to parse URL from /data.json.
What you can do is something like this :

```
import {getDataFromFile} from './data.js'

async function getData() {
  try {
    const data = getDataFromFile()
    return data;
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e.message);
  }
}
```

with `./data.js`

```
export const getDataFromFile = () => {
    return({dataFromFile: "I'm a data returned directly as json"})
}
```

Comment: hmm, i'm trying to use nextjs feature mentioned here: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/static-file-serving

in nextjs 13, they changed how you fetch data, but i'm assuming static file serving should still work, i'm just probly writing it wrong